# Chat box always scroll to bottom to the last chat line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a chat interface, but whenever any new chat is updated the chatbox does not scroll to the last line rather it stays in the top of the chat output box, now I need the chat box scroller to always scroll to the latest chat line. Here is the code so far:

```js
  var accessToken = "8b8205aeb6174669b372e6fecd40f9eb";
  var baseUrl = "https://api.api.ai/v1/";

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
     send();
    }
   });
   $("#rec").click(function(event) {
    switchRecognition();
   });
  });
  var recognition;
  function startRecognition() {
   recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
   recognition.onstart = function(event) {
    updateRec();
   };
   recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var text = "";
       for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        text += event.results[i][0].transcript;
       }
       setInput(text);
    stopRecognition();
   };
   recognition.onend = function() {
    stopRecognition();
   };
   recognition.lang = "en-US";
   recognition.start();
  }

  function stopRecognition() {
   if (recognition) {
    recognition.stop();
    recognition = null;
   }
   updateRec();
  }
  function switchRecognition() {
   if (recognition) {
    stopRecognition();
   } else {
    startRecognition();
   }
  }
  function setInput(text) {
   $("#input").val(text);
   send();
  }
  function updateRec() {
   $("#rec").text(recognition ? "Stop" : "Speak");
  }
  function send() {
   var text = $("#input").val();
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
     "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing" }),
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data)
     window.test = data;
     //setResponse(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
     // $("#res").append("<li class='list-group-item'>"+
     // "User says  -  " + data.result.resolvedQuery +
     // "<br/> Bot says - " +
     // data.result.fulfillment.speech
     // +"</li>");

     $("#res").append("<li class='user-bubble'>"+data.result.resolvedQuery + "</li>" +
      "<br/>" + "<li class='bot-bubble'>"+data.result.fulfillment.speech + "</li>");
    },
    error: function() {
     setResponse("Internal Server Error");
    }
   });
   setResponse("Loading...");
  }
  function setResponse(val) {
   $("#response").text(val);
  }
```

```css
  .chat-section{
   height: 500px;

   /*border: 1px solid grey;*/
   box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .chat-section:hover{

   /*transform: scale(1.05);*/
  }
  .chat-output{

    height: 450px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .chat-input{
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  }

  .bodnone{
   height: 40px !important;
   border: none;
  }
  .micicon{

   border: none;
   background: transparent;
   vertical-align: top;
  }

  .form-control{
   height: 30px;
   padding: 3px 12px;
  }

  .input-group-addon{

   font-size: 20px;
  }

  .user-bubble{
   display: inline-block;
     padding: 15px 25px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid #eee;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     font-size: 16px;
     clear: both;

  background-color: #efefef;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }

  .bot-bubble{
   display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: both;
   color: white;
    background-color: #A5D175;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b68a7e9cb4.js"></script>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Chat bot</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
 </div>
</nav>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <!-- <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
     <span class="input-group-addon" id="rec">Speak</span>
    </div> -->
    <!-- <br/><br/> -->
    <div class="chat-section" id="messages">
    <div class="chat-output" id="message">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="res">

    </ul>
    <div id="empty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group chat-input">
     <input type="text" id="input" class="form-control bodnone" placeholder="Ask Something..." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
     <span class="input-group-addon micicon" id="rec"><i class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    </div>


     <!-- <br>Response<br> <textarea id="response" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea> -->

   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
  </div>


    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have given fixed height to chat-output element and you are adding newly created element to list-unstyled. So height of list-unstyled is increasing when you are adding

```
  <li class='user-bubble'>"+data.result.resolvedQuery + "</li>" +
                  "<br/>" + "<li class='bot-bubble'>"+data.result.fulfillment.speech + "</li>
```

to existing list-unstyled element.
So you need to scrollTop chat-output element to new height of list-unstyled after adding a chat element.
Before that you need to add clearfix class to list-unstyled element as it was not clearing float of childrens to take proper height.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled clearfix" id="res"></ul>
```

Now you just need to scrollTop to new height of list-unstyled after adding new li element in send() function.
So just add last statement in success of your send() function.

```
$(".chat-output").scrollTop($(".list-unstyled").height());
```

and you are done. Enjoy.

Comment: your solution almost works but now when I give a new input I don't see the last chat group rather than the previous of the last one, so can u please give a suggestion so that I will be able to see the latest chat whenever I am in the chat box, thanks for the help so far @Brijesh Vishwakarma

Comment: Have you added $(".chat-output").scrollTop($(".list-unstyled").height()) after  $("#res").append("<li>some element</li>) statement?
You need to add $(".chat-output").scrollTop($(".list-unstyled").height()) as last statement of your success function.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
var messageArea = $('#res');
messageArea.scrollTop = messageArea.scrollHeight;
```

when you append new message to messages area (I assumed that is the messages div)

**EDIT**

ok i see where You put message to div:

```
$("#res").append("<li class='user-bubble'>"+data.result.resolvedQuery + "</li>" +
                    "<br/>" + "<li class='bot-bubble'>"+data.result.fulfillment.speech + "</li>");
```

after that you should put my code